# Plotting intersecating classes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of `data.frame` like the following:

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c("cat", "dog", "hello"), y2 = c(4, 5, 6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c("blue", "yellow", "bye"), y2 = c(6, 5, 4))
d3 <- data.frame(y1 = c("cat","yellow","good"),y2=c(1,2,1))
d4 <- data.frame(y1 = c("green","red","good"),y2=c(-1,2,0))
listlist <- list(d1,d2,d3,d4)
```

If we consider the `y1` variable of each `data.frame` as a set, then I would like to plot these resulting sets by highlighting them with different colours and accounting for their intersections. I show below an example:

[image]

it is a very crude and colorless example but it makes the idea.

Comment: Such a diagram is called a [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram). Does [this](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/13301_6641d73cfac741a59c0a851feb99e98b.html) help you?

Comment: @Bas, yes thank you. I will try to understand the code